# Let $A= $ {$10^n :n∈\mathbb Z$}. Find GLB$(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Can someone please explain to me how to do this?  I can’t find any examples of this sort of question.
Thanks.

Comment: To show that $x$ is a greatest lower bound of $A,$ show that $x$ is a lower bound of $A$ and that if $y>x$ then $y$ is not a lower bound of $A$

Answer (score 0):

We want to find
$$\inf{\{10^n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}}$$
Where $\inf{A}$ is the [Infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of a set $A$. As the function $f(x)=10^x$ is strictly increasing we can say that
$$\inf{\{10^n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}10^x=0$$

Comment: Thanks! is this enough to be a full answer, eg would it gain full marks in an exam cos I feel something would need to be added in order to gain full marks but im unsure what

Answer (score 0):

$0$ is a lower bound of $A= ${$10^n:n\in\mathbb Z$}, because, for all $n \in \mathbb Z,$ $10^n>0$.

For any $\epsilon>0$, we can take $N<\log_{10}\epsilon,$ and then $10^N<\epsilon,$ so no $\epsilon>0$ is a lower bound of $A$.

Therefore, $0$ is the greatest lower bound of $A.$

Comment: Thanks very much! Would this be all you need for an answer to this question, like is this all the working to gain all the marks

Comment: Yes, see my comment to your question regarding what you need to prove something is a greatest lower bound; we are taking some properties of exponentiation for granted (e.g., $10^n>0; N<\log\epsilon\implies 10^N<\epsilon$) but those are not what's being asked for here

Comment: $N$ is an element of $\mathbb Z$ less than $\log \epsilon$.   We could let $N$ be the greatest integer less than $\log \epsilon$, for example.